# how to ignore UNIQUE constraint failed in django rest framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to expand my user model and now I have added two more fields `public_address` and `nonce`.
Problem-
Now I do not require to store `username` and `email` and want to keep these fields empty while storing `public_address` and `nonce` only.

The error I am getting is-

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: user_user.username
```

my User model-

```
class User(AbstractUser):
username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
otp = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)
count = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text='Number of opt_sent')
public_address = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=500)
nonce = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=500)
validated = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                help_text='if it is true, that means user have validate opt correctly in seconds')
token_string = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

is there any way to ignore this error ?

thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried removing the username field and running migrations?

Comment: @NickODell I need it for other sign up API's. Thats the issue

Comment: Have you tried setting `unique=False` in the username field?